# Continuity of second partial derivatives: Could $F_{xy}$ be continuous while $F_{yx}$ is not?

Tags: partial-derivative

> **THEOREM $3.1$:**
>   If $f_{xy}(x, y)$ and $f_{yx}(x, y)$ are continuous on an open set containing $(a, b)$, then
>   $f_{xy}(a, b) = f_{yx}(a, b)$.

My question is: Could $F_{xy}$ be continuous while $F_{yx}$ is not? Is there example for this case ?

Thanks

Comment: It is certainly possible for $f_{xy}$ to be continuous while $f_{yx}$ does not exist.  This is one sense in which "$f_{yx}$ is continuous" could be false.

Comment: Could you please give an example of this case?

Comment: Just choose a sufficiently non-nice function which depends only on $y$.  Then the $y$-derivative won't be defined, so $f_{yx}$ does not exist, but $f_{x} = 0$ everywhere so $f_{xy} = 0$.